# Error (414) Request-URI Too Long when calling a wcf web service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I'm developing a wcf web service for one of our clients, and they reported an error I do not understand at all. 
First of all, what the wcf does: it just saves objects in a database they dont have access. That's all.
I've tested the wcf saving up to 100/150 objects.
But, when they call the web service, they cant even save 50 because it throws the exception "The remote server returned an error: (414) Request-URI Too Long".
I understand that each browser has a limit to the size of the url, but i really dont understand WHY, when calling the web service, they're having this problem.

Maybe this can help, but i think they call the web service from a web api and not directly from their webpage/app.

If anyone has an idea that could help me, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is nothing to do with their client per se. The 414 error is coming from your server because the Request-URI that they are passing it is too long. This is normally caused by the client performing an HTTP GET rather than a POST. Thus the querystring becomes too large when too many parameters are passed within it. Check that they are using a POST as this service clearly needs to be exposed using that verb.

Comment: So i must ask if they are using an HTTP POST in both requests (from the app to the web api and from the web api to the web service)?

Comment: You just need to ensure that the request to your service is using a POST as this is where the error originates from. Although you should be able to ascertain this from your web server logs - are you using IIS?

Comment: Yes, but they are testing the Web Service in their servers, that's why i dont really know what the server logs says.